# Подключение openssl к проекту Qt

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt, openssl

Как подключить openssl к проекту qt на ubuntu. openssl в убунте есть - проверял.

Пытался подключать в файле .pro:

```
QT += network
```

и ещё пытался исходники подцепить

```
#include "/openssl/crypto/rsa/rsa.h"
```

но ни то ни другое не помогает. Что я делаю не так, объясните?

Answer (score 1):

Поставить Qt 5.7 и использовать встроенные классы - обертки [QSsl*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ssl.html)

Comment: По ней примеров в сети вообще нет, тем более по rsa

Answer (score 1):

Скачай openssl из git репозитория и собери, а потом статическую библиотеки собранные их собственно 2 подключишь в профайле.

Comment: @NikitaSmith почему не содержится решения?